# Error "Cannot GET" url in browser after refresh a Redux component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm rendering the following component properly on the URL localhost:8080/productDesc/433899641 on first load navigating from another component.
However when refreshing the page, browser **does not load React and returns in the display the error message** "Cannot GET /productDesc/433899641" and nothing in the console to debug

```
import React from 'react'

const ProductDesc = (props)=>{

    function test(element,index,array){
      var convertId = Number(productId)
      if(element.id === convertId){
        return true;
      }
    }
    const products  = props.products;
    const productId = props.params.itemId;

    const i = products.findIndex(test);

    const product = products[i];
    console.log(product);

    return (
     <ProductComponent />
    )

}

ProductDesc.propTypes = {
  products: React.PropTypes.array
};

export default ProductDesc;
```

My routing is as below

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={ history }>
      <Route path="/" component={ App }>
          <IndexRoute component={ ProductsGrid } />
          <Route
            path="/productDesc/:itemId"
            component={ ProductDesc }
          />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

How am i supposed to keep the current state and reload it? I'm using Redux

Comment: The problem is not the client, but the server. When you enter the url in the browser it tries to map it to a ressource that's not there. Usually we use wildcards to always route it to the index.html, after which the client takes over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to survive the server reload, your server needs to support it too by responding with index.html no matter what path is requested. Otherwise, use hashHistory instead of browserHistory.

Comment: allright some more details on the feature https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: @Nicc I should have included the link. Thanks!